# How to disable Gridview Edit, Update , Cancel control for particular login type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using gridview "Edit, Update , Cancel" control for performing editing in gridview itself but i should not allow all users to edit the content. Only particular login type users like admin, manager etc should be able to see the edit button in gridview and other login type like workers should not be able to see the edit option in gridview and only they should be able to view the content in gridview. I am using C# ASP.Net to accomplish this process.

I have used a login form where all type of users have unique passwords to view same gridview content but not all login type members should be able to edit it. Please Suggest some solution.

Comment: i posted answer try that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply Hide those button on `UserRoles`

```
if(Session["UserRoles]!=null)
{
if(Session["UserRoles].ToString()=="workers")  
{
   //Make GridView Buttons Visible =False
}

}
```

**EDIT**

if You have implemented [Role Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can use `Roles.IsUserInRole` to Check Whether the currently logged-on user is in the specified role

[Roles.IsUserInRole Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I am just elaborating the answer given by @Ganesh_Devlekar.

You will need to implement a custom authorization framework. This would be one way to do it, after successful authentication of the login, return the login type. Put the user data into the session. On Load of the page: Check if user data in the session for the particular login type, and set the buttons accordingly.

Have a common method handle the disable/enable buttons. Set the page mode to required type by passing true or false to this method.

You will need to re-authenticate on session expiry so that you can fetch the user data that has the login type.